# Using of Indian passport and other national passport

Tags: eu-citizens, indian-citizens

What if I I get the visit visa to UAE and use my Indian passport to travel out of India and enter UAE. From  UAE I will use my Portuguese passport going out of UAE and entering UK. 1) will I be allowed to exit India and enter UAE after obtaining Portuguese passport as IWill have 2 passports in my hand? 2) will UAE immigration allow me to enter on Indian passport and use Portuguese passport which will not have entry stamp to go out of UAE?

Comment: You should be able to exit UAE with your Indian passport and enter your next destination with your Portuguese passport, but as far as I'm aware obtaining Portuguese nationality causes you to lose Indian nationality. If that is correct then using the Indian passport at all after obtaining the Portuguese passport would be a violation Indian law.  Whether you can use it to leave India therefore, as a practical matter, depends on whether India knows about your Portuguese nationality.

Comment: @phoog not only would it be a violation of Indian law, it would be a criminal offence.

Comment: @greatone I'm sure.  It's not entirely clear to me, however, *which* criminal offence or offences would be committed by using an Indian passport in these circumstances.  Do you know?  (It is also probable that using the Indian passport after loss of Indian nationality would violate the law, probably including criminal law, of the country to whose officer the Indian passport is presented, but I suppose the chance of prosecution is far lower.)

Comment: @phoog a person ceases to be an Indian citizen the moment he acquires another citizenship. To knowingly use an Indian passport that a person is no longer entitled to violates the Passport Act. In my view, immigration laws are incompatible with human dignity and in 100 years nationality-based discrimination will be seen in the same way we see racism today.

Comment: @greatone I overlooked the offense of "contravening the provisions of section 3." I suppose the passport legally ceases to be valid notwithstanding its nominal period of validity when the holder loses Indian nationality, but it's not explicit in the act. The section on revocation and so on largely implies that this should be done only with the knowledge of the holder. I'm interested because this would determine whether it is a violation of 12(1) or 12(3).  The former carries a maximum sentence of 2 years or INR 5000 while for the latter the maximum is 3 months or INR 500.

Comment: @phoog the chances of prosecution are extremely low.